# TYPO3 Powermail - upload form - file has to be overwritten if a file with same name already exists

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

I am using powermail extension to create a form for upload of several file types. This form is located in a login area. For every logged in user there is a folder with its name created where the uploaded files are stored.

```
# get personal storage folder for logged in user
lib.userfolder = TEXT
lib.userfolder {
  data = TSFE:fe_user|user|username
  wrap = fileadmin/user_upload/|/
  required = 1
}

# Powermail file upload settings
plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.misc.file {
folder = fileadmin/user_upload/
size = {$plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.uploadSize}
extension = {$plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.uploadFileExtensions}
randomizeFileName = {$plugin.tx_powermail.settings.misc.randomizeFileName}
}
```

this works fine so far. The problem is that if a file with a name "example.pdf" already exists and another file named "example.pdf" is uploaded the file is not overwritten. Instead the uploaded file "example.pdf" will be renamed to "example_01.pdf". A good behaviour in general but not fitting my needs. I need an approach to handle this problem would be nice to get some hints here.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the old files is default behaviour in powermail. 
Overwrite existing files is not implemented.

Possibilities:
- Building an own uploader in a finisher class (see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForDevelopers/AddFinisherClasses/Index.html)
- Overwriting the existing uploader \In2code\Powermail\Domain\Service\UploadService with e.g. a XClass
- Clearing the uploaded files every X hours (probably no option)

Comment: first one looks like a nice approach. will try this. thank you so far.